# How to avoid submitting text which is not in suggested datalist

Tags: javascript, php, html

Problem is I don't want user to put a search string that is not suggested by datalist.For example.my datalist suggests user the following:

> Nahid's Kichen
>
> Italian Dishes
>
> ABC Restaurant

In this case,user can put a value other than this 3 option,such as

> Chinese

I don't user to be able to put what he wants,I want a user must have to select between suggested 3 options.

If you need any clearification,please knock me.Thank You,

Abstract code is given below:

```
<input type="text" name="search" list="categoryname" autocomplete="off" id="pcategory" style="width:200px;height:40px; border:1px thick;font-weight:bold" placeholder="Location or Restaurant" required/>
 <datalist id="categoryname">
    <?php while($row = $qry->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option   value="<?php echo  $row['acc_id']."=".$row['res_name']." , ".$row['res_city'];?>"><?php echo $row['res_name']." , ".$row['res_city']." , ".$row['res_country']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a custom validation function when the search button is clicked, to ensure that the search value corresponds with one of the available values in the list of restaurants.

**Working Example:**

```js
// Create list of valid restaurant names
var restaurants = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
var restaurantList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
    restaurantList[i] = restaurants[i].getAttribute('value');
}



var searchBox = document.getElementById('pcategory');
var searchSubmit = document.querySelector('[type="submit"]');

function checkSearch() {
    if (restaurantList.indexOf(searchBox.value) === -1) {
        window.alert(searchBox.value + ' is not a valid selection - please choose from the list');
        searchBox.value = '';
    }
}

searchSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkSearch, false);
```

```css
input {
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px thick rgb(127,127,127);
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" list="categoryname" autocomplete="off" id="pcategory" placeholder="Location or Restaurant" required/>
<datalist id="categoryname">
<option value="Nahid's Kitchen">Nahid's Kitchen</option>
<option value="Italian Dishes">Italian Dishes</option>
<option value="ABC Restaurant">ABC Restaurant</option>
</datalist>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag is what you want. If you don't want any other user input, try to use it :

```
<select name="search" id="pcategory" style="width:200px;height:40px; border:1px thick;font-weight:bold" required>
    <option value="">Location or Restaurant</option>
    <?php while($row = $qry->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo  $row['acc_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['res_name']." , ".$row['res_city']." , ".$row['res_country']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks but Sorry.I know that.But I don't want it in elect.I want it in datalist.